# Tor in WINE = Anonymous?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, debian

*Could you tell me whether running a Tor.exe in the WINE emulator
under Debian might compromise anonymity?*

Background:
I need to run Tor Browser together with a password manager.

The only option I see is using Dashlane for Windows together
with a Windows version of the Tor Browser Bundle.
Pretty inelegant though. I just was not able, even after numerous attempts,
to get KeePass to work on my Debian.

I can run Dashlane well on Wine though.
Maybe Wine offers a workaround here.

Yet I am concerned about compromising my anonymity.

Comment: Installing KeePassX in my Debian was as simple as `sudo apt-get install keepassx`

Answer (score 3):

If the application appears to be running correctly under Wine, you can assume it is fully functional. The execution environment should not affect the application's behaviour.

One consideration is that perhaps malware targeting Windows can now attack your Tor session.